# In Objective-C, what gets called before main?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, what gets called before main? For example, I assume all metaclasses in Objective-C get instantiated before main and their load/initialize methods called, global constants, etc.  What else? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I think it is same as C++ plus `+load`

Comment: I'm curious why you're curious. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I always assumed that with Objective-C's dynamic nature that load/initialize get called 'just in time'.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I am trying to gain an understanding of things.

Comment: Three votes to close a question that's so clear and specific. Stop the madness.

Comment: @JasperBlues load doesn't get called just in time - it's done before main.  initialize possibly is JIT (during the first message sent to the class).

Answer (score 2):

A `+load` method which is part of any class in your application (not in any loaded framework) will be executed before `main()`. The full order of execution is given in the `+load` documentation (`NSObject` class reference):

> The `load` message is sent to classes and categories that are both dynamically loaded and statically linked, but only if the newly loaded class or category implements a method that can respond.
>
> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> • All initializers in any framework you link to.
>
> • All `+load` methods in your image.
>
> • All C++ static initializers and C/C++ `__attribute__(constructor)` functions in your image.
>
> • All initializers in frameworks that link to you.
>
> In addition:
>
> • A class’s `+load` method is called after all of its superclasses’ `+load` methods.
>
> • A category `+load` method is called after the class’s own `+load` method.
>
> In a custom implementation of load you can therefore safely message other unrelated classes from the same image, but any load methods implemented by those classes may not have run yet.

So if you add a `+load` to, say, your app delegate class it will run before `main()`.

HTH

Comment: What about the metaclasses of weak-linked frameworks?

Comment: @Boon - any `+load` methods in a framework are executed when the framework is loaded by the dynamic linker, whenever (and if) that occurs. Weak-linking is orthogonal to this and enables an application to execute with or without a particular framework.

Comment: What I mean is the metaclass objects are probably instantiated as well, otherwise call such as [MPPlayableContentManager class] to check if the current OS version supports the API won't work.  Is my guess correct?

Comment: @Boon - Consider the first bullet and the last para of the quote, do they imply a weak-linked framework will be loaded before your main image? Place a symbolic breakpoint on `load` and watch.