# [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured

Tags: ios, firebase

I have installed this three pods in my native iOS Swift/ObjC App:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

Here is call of config method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

I have this message in logs:

```
[Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: https ....
```

I don't know where is problem. I see similar in the Internet, but related with technologies like: React Native, Cordova, Flutter ... Any one have idea what happens in my native project?

I have double checked Google Info Plist files and configuration in the console and I have never had this type of behavior before.

Xcode Version ***11.2.1*** (11B500)

Comment: I had the same problem, but could find the solution

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the app is calling Firebase APIs in a `+load` or `+initialize` method.  More details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23992142/556617

Comment: Nope. I have configuration at `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool`

Answer (score 0):

This error is logged because the app is trying to access `FirebaseApp.app()` before it is configured. Jump to definition to `app()` (or `defaultApp` for Objective-C) function in Firebase SDK and add a breakpoint there to see where this function is called.

You can see the error from Firebase SDK here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRApp.m#L235-L241

Answer (score -3):

This solution worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046033/9682885

Just add this line in your AppDelegate

> FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: Isn't that literally what OP is doing?