# My Flutter/Firebase app is showing no app has been configured yet

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am making an app in Flutter/Firebase and I am experiencing the following error on my visual studio code terminal:

```
Xcode build done.                                           522.2s
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications 
proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd 
prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add 
"FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow 
the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud- 
messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
Waiting for iPhone 11 to report its views...                         9ms
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...                               610ms
```

Comment: did you add `GoogleService-Info.plist` in your project?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I solved the issue. If you are using swift in your AppDelegate.swift, make sure you've added the following in that order:

```
import Firebase


FirebaseApp.configure() //add this before the code below
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

If you're using flutter with objective-c, add the following to your appdelgate.m file:-

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[FIRApp configure]; //add this right after the above
```

Comment: OK. Here's a super funny (aka odd) thing. I have two projects that connect to the same FireBase. One wouldn't build, I used this solution AND IT WORKED.

The other one doesn't have the FirebaseApp.configure(), but it works too.

I'm sure there is an alternate way to do this, and I'll report back when I figure it out.

Comment: Same thing started to happen here after update flutter to 2.0.1. This worked for me as well. But still doesn't understand why I had to update the AppDelegate.swift file. Feels the same @CurtEckhart, have you found why?

Comment: (for swift)As mentioned below you have to import firebase at the top

`import Firebase`

Answer (score 28):

with adding `FirebaseApp.configure()`, do not forget to `import Firebase`.

`AppDelegate.swift` file  should start like this:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
```

Comment: You need to tell where it needs to put otherwise only iOS Devs will understand.

Comment: he's talking about iOS/Runner/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Thanks, @elder, That saved me.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another method to initialize Firebase which is done by editing your main.dart.

This is probably the preferred solution, because it doesn't initialize Firebase until all of your application widgets are initialized. I had a situation where some Widgets weren't working because their reference to the Firebase instance was null.

*WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();* is necessary to do class initialization.

Although the solution given by Sai works, I suspect it doesn't always work due to a subtle initialization issue.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that making this change to your main.dart will properly initialize your app for connection to Firebase.

Comment: Did not work for me on flutter 2.1.0. Had to edit the AppDelegate.swift as mentioned on the accepted answer.

Comment: Mine also solved when I added for both AppDelegate.swift and main() flutter

Answer (score 7):

I also had 'No app has been configured yet' message, this is just a warning, after call
`await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission` and accept permission(IOS need permission from user), I will get notification from FCM. Of course, on my main function, I need to add these(for new Dart initialization).

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

No need add 'GoogleService-Info' and `FirebaseApp.configure()` in AppDelegate anymore, because FlutterFire now supports initialization directly from Dart!
New Dart initialization document here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/

Comment: Can you explain this further? The answer is not very concise. I'm using the new Dart initialization, although I'm receiving the missing GoogleServices log as well.

Comment: @BretHagen, I edited my answer a little bit. I mean if you following new Dart initialization from document, you can get notification even though you get this message 'No app has been configured yet', may be this message at this time just a warning. FlutterFire document here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/

Comment: you are right, the warning just showing for no affection. With the FlutterFire latest version, we don't need to manually configure anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In AppDelegate File

1. import Firebase
2. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` just above the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self).