# [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet

Tags: firebase, flutter

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492211/no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-initializeapp-in) post's all solutions, I'm using

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(...)
}
```

But I still see this error in my console:

> 8.9.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.

I tested it on both a simulator and a real device. However, all Firebase operations are working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This might be late to answer but adding

```
import Firebase
...
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

to ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift just before

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

solved the problem for me. I did not have the Flutter Android app ready so did not try it on that.

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046033/18779466).

Comment: add import Firebase

Comment: @SyedAsadAli Now `import FirebaseCore`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. If you are using Swift in your AppDelegate.swift, please ensure that you have added the following in the specified order:

```
import Firebase

FirebaseApp.configure() //add this before the code below
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

If you're working with Flutter and Objective-C, please incorporate the following code into your AppDelegate.m file:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[FIRApp configure]; //add this right after the above
```