# Flutter FCM Push notification not receiving on iOS version 17 and higher

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

### FCM integration in flutter for both android and iOS working fine but in IOS version 17 and higher have issue with receiving notifications.

Working Log from Xcode (iPhone 6  - OS 12.5.7)

2024-02-14 15:51:15.018527+0530 Runner[3954:1610082] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful

2024-02-14 15:51:15.362210+0530 Runner[3954:1609804] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled

2024-02-14 15:51:15.364673+0530 Runner[3954:1609804] Metal API Validation Enabled

2024-02-14 15:51:15.510020+0530 Runner[3954:1609804] [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.

2024-02-14 15:51:15.576132+0530 Runner[3954:1609804] Warning: Unable to create restoration in progress marker file

2024-02-14 15:51:15.622166+0530 Runner[3954:1610089] 10.18.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.

2024-02-14 15:51:15.900749+0530 Runner[3954:1610108] 10.18.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging

to ensure proper integration.

2024-02-14 15:51:16.549756+0530 Runner[3954:1610137] flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:59171/Oe3wrp1-4Cc=/

### Not Working Log from Xcode (iPhone 15 Pro Max  - OS 17.2)

Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/netleonmacmini1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxrpknwazrikifclwsmycdqtkvaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

objc[70696]: Class AKAlertImageURLProvider is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21C62/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKitUI.framework/AuthKitUI (0x148498628) and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21C62/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AuthKit.framework/AuthKit (0x12cba59a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.

10.18.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.

flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:56253/N2crEqoovMY=/

10.18.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging

to ensure proper integration.

flock failed to lock list file (/Users/netleonmacmini1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2949BA35-4676-4E86-B051-76A10CA25162/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE280BC4-1126-4100-A286-830EAEDB7263/Library/Caches/com.dmh.employee/com.apple.metal//functions.list): errno = 35

fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)

Errors found! Invalidating cache...

Failed to change device orientation: Error Domain=BSActionErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=timeout}

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C3] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C3] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C3] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C6] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C6] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C6] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C4] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C4] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C9] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C9] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C9] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C7] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C7] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C12] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C12] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C12] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C10] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C10] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C13] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C13] Connection has no local endpoint

quic_conn_process_inbound [C13.1.1.1:2] [-f48390ee349469ae] unable to parse packet

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C17] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint_block_invoke [C17] Client called nw_connection_copy_connected_remote_endpoint on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C17] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C15] Connection has no local endpoint

nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C15] Connection has no local endpoint

### Is there any changes for new iOS versions? I didn't find any solution regarding this.

Working fine in android all versions, in iOS working fine till version 16.

Also verified from app setting (version 17 and above), Notification permissions enabled.

Also get success from this API -

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

response -

```
{
    "multicast_id": 9120446600988460020,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1707912204556015%c88f660af9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This message "No app has been configured yet" worries me that something with config is off. Can you verify that is set up correctly?

Comment: @bqubique Same message for lower iOS versions but receiving notifications, only higher versions not receiving.

Comment: Can you still try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046033/11118209,  just to be on the safe side :).

Comment: Include your code that concerns firebase messaging

Comment: I have tried all I can find regarding this but Notification not receiving on higher versions. Also I want to mention that if there anything wrong with implementation then why lower iOS version receiving notifications.